# Получить PHP массив с JSON

Tags: php, массивы, json

Здравствуйте. Пытаюсь получить PHP массив с JSON и вывести все названия городов по стране. Ничего не выводит. Json валидный, проверял [здесь](http://jsonlint.com). В чем моя ошибка?

```
$json[] = file_get_contents('http://turmagnat-demo.ideaperm.ru/hotels/Output_1.json');

$array = json_decode($json, true);

$country = "Ямайка";
$city = "";

foreach ( $array  as $key => $value){
    if($value['country'] == $country) {
        $city .= $value['city'];
    }
}

echo $city;
```

Пример JSON файла:

```
[
  {
    "id": "al130489",
    "sourceUrl": "http://tophotels.ru/hotel/al130489",
    "country": "США",
    "city": "Висконсин",
    "name": "Hilton Garden Inn Appleton/Kimberly 3*",
    "description": null,
    "reviews": [],
    "images": []
  },
  {
    "id": "al277646",
    "sourceUrl": "http://tophotels.ru/hotel/al277646",
    "country": "Италия",
    "city": "Лидо ди Камайоре",
    "name": "Villa Il Fortino",
    "description": null,
    "reviews": [],
    "images": []
  }
]
```

Comment: вместо `$json[]` надо `$json`.... либо тогда уж `json_decode($json[0], true);`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, Да, в этом и была проблема

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно вы зря в массив помещаете данные, попробуйте так

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://turmagnat-demo.ideaperm.ru/hotels/Output_1.json');

$array = json_decode($json, true);
```

Comment: Да, всё верно, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

А еще лучше всегда проверить что json преобразовался в массив, иначе получите ошибку invalid argument supplied foreach, **json_decode** в случае ошибки вернет вам **NULL** вместо массива, поэтому лучше так:

```
$array = json_decode($json, true) ?? [];
```

либо

```
$array = json_decode($json, true) ?: [];
```

Comment: Да, лучше перестраховаться, спасибо